# Query Array of Arrays Of Hashes using Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model that has a column that looks like this (example):

```
column = [{:A => "1", :B => "2"}, [a, b, c, ..., n]]
```

Where `a`, `b`, `c` and `n` are also hashes, like this (example):

```
a = {:X => "x", :Y => "y"}
```

Currently, if I call a record `m` of the Model, for example, `m.column[0][:A]` it returns `=> "1"`
And if I call `m.column[1][0]` I get `a = {:X => "x", :Y => "y"}`

So far, so good.

Now the question is, how can I get an Array of all the records of the Model that has, for example, `column[0][:A] = "1"` ???

I'm trying something like this (but it isn't working):

```
Model.where("column[0][:A] = ?", "1")
```

The error says:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
```

**EDIT:**

`column` is a `text` datatype
and in its model it has `serialize :column, Array`

Comment: What does the table really look like, what is its schema? Is `column` an array column? JSONB? Something else?

Comment: I'll edit with that information

Comment: @muistooshort you can see now

Comment: Can you change the schema so that you don't use `serialize`? `serialize` is an ugly kludge that just slops a big pile of YAML into the database so you're pretty much out of luck as parsing YAML in SQL will be highly unpleasant.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but with `array` datatype I couldn't find a way to build the column in a way so I can then do `m.column[0][:A]`. It showed an error. I need to be able to do that. @muistooshort

Comment: If you can tell me how can I do to be able to do exactly what I posted, I could change the datatype. @muistooshort

Comment: Sorry for the delay, untangling this `serialize` thing is sort of complicated.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you're using `serialize` to store your data and `serialize` just slops a big pile of unqueryable YAML into the database. Parsing YAML inside PostgreSQL is certainly possible but it would be slow and a little pointless.

If you really need to store an array of hashes then PostgreSQL's `jsonb` type would be your best bet. You won't get symbol keys in the database but you will get string keys so this Ruby data:

```
[{:A => "1", :B => "2"}, {:C => 6, :D => 11}]
```

would look like this JSON:

```
[ { "A": "1", "B": "2" }, { "C": 6, "D": 11 } ]
```

inside the database.

Once you have `jsonb` in the database, you can query it using all the [JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) that PostgreSQL providers and you could even index the JSON to support faster querying. In your case, your query would look like:

```
Model.where("column->0->>'A' = ?", '1')
```

the `->` operator with an integer on the RHS acts like Ruby's `Array#[]` method:

> `->` `int`
>   Get JSON array element (indexed from zero, negative integers count from the end)

With a string on the RHS it acts like Ruby's `Hash#[]`. Note that `->` returns JSON, not text or integer. The `->>` operator is the same as `->` but it returns text so you'd use that at the end to make the comparison cleaner.

Alternatively you could say:

```
Model.where("column->0->'A' = ?", '1'.to_json)
```

to push the string-vs-JSON logic into Ruby.

---

Everything is pretty easy once your database schema makes sense (i.e. it is using PostgreSQL's `jsonb` instead of Rails's `serialize`) but how do you get there from here? First remove the `serialize :column, Array` from your model, then you'd need a three step migration something like this:

1. Add a `jsonb` column:

   ```
   def change
     add_column :models, :column_j, :jsonb
   end
   ```
2. Read each `column` value from the database, unpack the YAML by hand, and write the JSON by hand:

   ```
   def up
     connection.execute('select id, column from models').each do |row|
       a = YAML.load(row['column'])
       connection.raw_connection.exec(
         'update models set column_j = $1 where id = $2',
         [ a.to_json, row['id'].to_i ]
       )
     end
   end
   ```

   Note that you can't use the model for this as the model class and the database no longer agree about the structure and format of the `models` table.
3. Replace the old `column` with the new `column_j`:

   ```
   def change
     remove_column :models, :column, :text
     rename_column :models, :column_j, :column
   end
   ```

You'll want to backup your database before migrating of course. And hopefully you'll never even think about using `serialize` again, `serialize` is a horrible kludge that seems like an easy solution but quickly turns into an RPG aimed right at your foot.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I actually changed the datatype to JSON yesterday, and now I'm changing the way I collect the input data from users to store it accordingly. I'm changing nested models to that one JSON column, seems a lot cleaner.