# How to query a JSONB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am building a Rails 5.2 app. I am using Postgres.
In this app I have a User object and in this object i got a JSONB column.

I need to be able to query specific attributes within the JSONB object.

**This is how I define it in the User model:**

```
serialize :preferences
store_accessor :preferences, PREFERENCES
```

**This is the content of the object:**

```
{"digest_is_active"=>true, "digest_frequency"=>"modal", "digest_time"=>"10:00"}
```

**I tried this:**

```
scope :digest_active, -> { where("preferences @> ?", { "digest_is_active": true }.to_json) }

User.where("preferences->>'digest_time' = ?", "10:00")
```

The query seems to run without errors but cannot find the User object.

```
 SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (preferences @> '{"digest_is_active":true}') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Comment: What you show as the content of the object is not valid JSON.

Comment: What is that final query you show, is that your rails code actually produces, or is that you want it to produce?

Comment: @jjanes the query is what my scope outputs when executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
serialize :preferences
```

That will encode your Ruby hash as a blob of YAML text and then that string will go into your `jsonb` column. A string is valid JSON so the database will be fine with this but it won't understand the internal structure so the database's JSON operators won't be much use.

Remove the `serialize` from your model, fix any existing data, and you should have more luck with your queries.

Comment: Sounds interesting, what do you mean by "fix any existing data"? How can I convert?

Comment: Pull each column value out, decode the YAML, put it back into the database as proper JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40555436/479863